# How to move array index key to new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array data like this

```
 Array(
 [0] => stdClass Object
        ([iditem] => 31702152
         [idcolor] => 39 )
 [1] => stdClass Object
        ([iditem] => 31702152
        [idcolor] => 38))
```

So I want to put each `idcolor` to new variable `$colorid` and the result are `38,39`.
I can't find match keyword, or can I get the link of similar question ?

Comment: Use `array_column`, it now supports array of objects in PHP 7 - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: have you try `foreach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Array implementation and implode

```
$ids = [];
foreach($youarray as $value) {
    $ids[] = $value->idcolor;
}

$finalIds = implode(',', $ids);
```

### Using string concatenation and rtrim

```
$finalIds = '';
foreach($youarray as $value) {
    $finalIds = $value->idcolor.',';
}

$finalIds = rtrim($finalIds, ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**array_map**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) which map/return the new array as it was designed to this kind of job, supposed this :

```
// creating array of object
$a = (object) array('iditem' => 31702151,'idcolor' => 38 );
$b = (object) array('iditem' => 31702152,'idcolor' => 39 );
// placing above data to new array container
$ab = array($a,$b);

// callback function
function getData( $obj ) {
  return $obj->idcolor;
}

// array_map the array using above callback
$colorid = array_map("getData", $ab );

print_r( $colorid );
```

Above code will produce `Array( [0] => 39, [1] => 38 )`. If you want it value directly stored in variable as a single string separate it by commas, just use the **[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)** function to do so :

```
$newStr = implode(',', $colorid );
// which will produce 38,39
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want `$colorid` to be an array with all the ids if I understand correctly right?

```
$colorid = array();

foreach($array as $object)
    array_push($colorid, $object->idcolor);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) for the job:

```
<?php

// your data
$data = array(
  (object) array('iditem' => 31702152, 'idcolor' => 39),
  (object) array('iditem' => 31702152, 'idcolor' => 38),
);

// the code
$output = array_reduce($data, function($carry, $obj) {
  if (isset($obj->idcolor)) $carry[] = $obj->idcolor;
  return $carry;
}, array());
sort($output); // directly sort the $output variable
```

`$output` will be:

```
array(38, 39);
```